# What medical conditions are considered Treyfah nowadays?

Tags: halacha, medicine

*This question is a part of a series on "death hastening".*

As I understand, [the Treyfah condition](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%94#.D7.98.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.A4.D7.AA_.D7.90.D7.93.D7.9D) in humans is when one is destined to die in the foreseeable future (12 months?) with a high degree of certainty (see also [WIKI](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%94#%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D)).

I presume the advances in technology and medicine had shaken some of those definitions.

What medical conditions are considered Treyfah nowadays? And what had changed from the classical Rabbinical knowledge?

Comment: למאי נפקא מינה?

Comment: @JoelK One who kills a Treyfah is Potur. If one is infected with a deadly virus or has a Treyfah condition we might see the hastening differently.

Comment: We don’t put people to death for murder nowadays, so I think it is unlikely that contemporary poskim would have addressed this issue (unlike perhaps animal treifot which are still very relevant)

Comment: @JoelK Animal medical conditions can be treated similarly. Most conditions that apply to humans and other mammals tend to be physiologically identical across species and can be treated the same way. (Obviously when it comes to medication, the dosing is different, but the same medication works across species.) As such, I think the question may well have been addressed by modern-day poskim in respect to animals, even if it wasn’t addressed in respect to humans.

Comment: You should explain what qualifies a human as a treifah and the ramifications thereof. While I and many other users know Hebrew, not everyone on MY does and, as such, pertinent information should be available in English

Comment: @DonielF animal treifot are just a list mentioned by Chazal unconnected to medical realia. The assumption here is that human treifot are a medical reality and not a formal law.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is that list exhaustive and, perhaps more importantly for this question, immutable?

Comment: @doniel animal treifot? Yes.